# Liquid shield for spacecraft?

Tags: spacecraft, interplanetary, the-sun, shielding, design-alternative

Could an alloy of hot or cold liquid metal be made magnetic by adding electricity to the molten ball to give it magnetic properties to wirelessly attach it to a space craft to use as a shield shown in the 3rd picture?

[What is the shielding capability of liquid metal compaired to solid metal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/shielding-capability-of-liquid-metals)

[image]
https://www.geek.com/geek-cetera/this-is-how-you-melt-metal-with-magnets-1544652/ Shows how hot liquid metal can still have magnetic properties.

[image]

Ferrofluid Source: Reddit Oil firming from applying artificial magnetic field.

[image]

[What is the shielding capability of liquid metal compaired to solid metal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/what-is-the-shielding-capability-of-liquid-metal-compaired-to-solid-metal)

Comment: Just read wikipedia about the [Curie point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) Liquid iron is not magnetic.

Comment: What is the effect of an externally applied magnetic field to a not magnetic metall?

Comment: @Uwe: Seems OP is confusing "not magnetic" with "not ferromagnetic (but possibly paramagnetic or diamagnetic)"

Comment: @Muze Liquid iron is not ferromagnetic. An external magnetic field would not change this.

Comment: Surely this question would be a better fit over on Physics?

Comment: Could you mix iron with something ferromagnetic to make a ferromagnetic alloy which would behave like a ferromagnetic material when in liquid form? (Ferromagnetic is a fun word to say).

Comment: Oh, really? That's cool! I don't know how you'd keep the alloy molten and mobile (like the liquids) though, that putty/oil doesn't seem to be very shielding!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn   Micrometeorites would leave damage to the cold metal. The metal would be exited by induction to melt then repaired by a applied magnetic field. Initially it was a question how how to improve the Parker shield to melt and still shield against the Sun.

Comment: @Muze oh, that does sound really cool in theory!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn is it more clear now?

Comment: I think this may be a better fit for physics to be honest, I'm not the person to ask at all that's for sure.

Comment: The commonly-used [Whipple shields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipple_shield) rely on having a thin rigid outer layer separated from the main hull by a gap.  On contact with the solid outer layer, the impactor shatters into a spray that can be stopped pretty easily by the inner hull because its force is now spread over a much larger area.  I have my doubts that a solid or liquid ferromagnetic shield would be an effective replacement for this.  Two big issues I see are the required mass and (especially for a solid shield) [spalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spall) of the inner hull.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn You may mix ferromagnetic alloys from several materials, but when the alloy is liquid, it is not ferromagnetic anymore.

Comment: @Uwe  I've watched a YouTube video on the.  first picture I have in the examples. The liquid metal does not fall in till they cut the power to that coil . they are suspending and heating the metal with a magnetic field. That can only be done if that liquid metal still has a magnetic property.

Comment: @Muze you are wrong again, the liquid metal has no magnetic property. The metal is conducting the induced current caused by the power to the coil. The coil is powered by high frequency alternating current. The magnetic fields of the coil and the field caused by the induced current within the molten metal interact and generate the lift force. Please read wikipedia carefully about [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current). Especially the chapter about Repulsive effects and levitation.

Comment: @Uwe the liquid metal is reacting with the magnetic field being applied. In the model I propose that this field can be reversed to attract and even shape the molten metal to the shield. I will draw it soon

Comment: @Muze An alternating magnetic field like that of the heating coil shown above could not be reversed. Attraction instead of repulsion is impossible. You may reverse a DC current but not an AC current. But for heating of the metal probe a high frequency AC field is needed, a DC field would not do it.

Comment: After thinking a little bit on it, I wouldn't close it out. It is clearly not practical with the current space technology. It will probably require some metal with a low melting point, otherways keepings it molten will require a tremendous power. But I don't think it is an inherently a bad idea. Reopen vote cast.

Comment: @peterh it will go molten as it comes close to the sun.

Comment: @Muze I've thought you are thinking on some regenerative technology against micrometeorites. The Sun is $\approx$ 6000K hot, the melting point of tungsten is $\approx$ 3700K. A tungsten mirror will help more. If it is so close to the Sun that even Tungsten melts, then another problem happens: the radiation of the molten tungsten (being at least 3700K) will be around so hard than the Sun's.

Comment: @Muze I think a probe can go most close to the Sun if a tungsten mirror protects it, which is also cooled from behind. The [Parker Solar Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) is going to approximate the Sun to around 8.5 solar radii, they use tungsten but no active cooling (as far I know). They expect a 2000K hot sunny side.

Comment: @peterh yes I understand that but Tungsten has a melting point and that is the limit of range as in the proximity to the sun. The distance can be decreased if the limit was based on the boiling point instead of the melting point a metal and if it can be magnetically stabilized.

Comment: @Muze Ok, but the molten tungsten itself (being at least 3700K) radiates nearly so much than the Sun (6000K). You will need an additional layer to defend from the heat radiation of the molten tungsten.

Comment: @peterh The liquid shield would be electrified to also have an EM field this would further repel. I would compose the liquid shield with liquid iron and tungsten powder which is weakly magnetic. I wonder what other metals are magnetic with a high melting point? I'm trying to say with a powerful enough magnet one could shape liquid molten metal into a dome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could liquid metal be made ferromagnetic by externally inducing an internal magnetic field?

No. Metal is either ferromagnetic or not; this is a result of the quantum-mechanical interaction of neighbouring atoms in the metal's crystal lattice. Even non-magnetised iron at room temperature is ferromagnetic, only, the [Weiss domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) are randomly oriented and mostly cancel out, which can be changed by applying an external field to orient them all in the same direction. Most other metals aren't ferromagnetic and an external field can't do anything about this: there *are* no magnetic domains that you could align in some way. And as Uwe commented, even the ferromagnetic metals are only ferromagnetic below the [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature). This always lies below the melting point, so no: liquid metals can not be made ferromagnetic.

Regarding ferrofluids: yes, those are ferromagnetic liquids, but they aren't liquid metals. In vacuum, the carrier would quickly freeze and/or evaporate.

**But I don't think that's really what you meant to ask anyway**: ferromagnetism is not the only way metals can interact with magnetic fields. There are three other mechanisms:

- [**Paramagnetism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism) is similar to ferromagnetism, except you don't have mesoscopic magnetic domains that could be aligned, but only microscopic spins of single atoms or molecules. Thus, paramagnets are attracted to magnets similarly as ferromagnets are, just much weaker.
  Many materials are paramagnetis, including liquids. Often they aren't metals, e.g. liquid oxygen is an example.
- [**Diamagnetism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) is even weaker, and has the opposite effect: diamagnets are repelled by an inhomogeneous magnetic field.
- [**Induction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction). Any conductor, and thus any metal even if liquid, will respond to a *time-variable* magnetic field: such a field generates currents, and those currents will broadly speaking reject the field-change. And this can indeed be used to move/shape the conductor without touching it. It is mostly important for plasma (conductive gas), and is the working principle behind [Tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak) and [Stellarator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarator) fusion reactors.

So, induction is your best bet. Could this be used to form a shield? Possibly. In fact fluid conductors have a natural tendency to form [sheet-like structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_sheet). Whether this is practical is dubious, but it's in principle a worthwhile idea.