# What is the vapor pressure limit of liquid metals in space?

Tags: physics, vacuum, design-alternative, thermodynamics, composite-materials

Would liquid metal be stable in space unlike most other liquids like water? **Are there any metals that has a high vapor pressure limit?**

Side question: Can liquid metal be given an electromagnetic field if electricity is passed through it?

[Liquid shield for spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/liquid-shield-for-spacecraft)

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/could-the-sun-have-liquid-iron-in-orbit

Comment: It is not called the Armstrong limit it is called the [vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question has been evolving. I've addressed the original:

> Are there any metals that has a high Armstrong limit?

I've never heard of a liquid metal that boils at 20° C or 37° C in a vacuum. Metallic hydrogen might be suggested but that's not a liquid at atmospheric pressure. So I think the answer is pretty much

### All of them!

Things like mercury or gallium (>30° C) would just sit there as liquids at 2 atmospheres, 1 atmosphere, or vacuum. They have low (but non-zero) vapor pressures but they wouldn't suddenly boil. Ditto for most eutectics as well.

Comment: The Armstrong limit is not at 20 °C, it is at 37 °C.

Comment: @Uwe added, thanks.

Comment: @Muze "near the Sun" has nothing to do with the Armstrong limit.

Comment: There is a [paper](https://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=50282) about the vapor pressure of mercury. See page 10 figure 1 for a graph of pressure and temperature. At 300 K the vapor pressure of mercury is less than 1 Pa, a pretty good vacuum. So liquid mercury at 37 °C will indeed boil in a vacuum (better than 1 Pascal). The dynamic of boiling depends on the heat energy transfered.

Comment: Yes but would the suns roche limit pull apart the ball?

Comment: @Muze It depends totally on the size and distance, and that should be addressed in a new question post.

Comment: @uhoh astronomy?

Comment: no, here. I edited my comment.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: If you are talking about a new and different question (not here) then yes that could be a really interesting question. "How close to the Sun could an iron meteor get before it melted, and how big could it be before the resulting liquid sphere would be pulled apart by Roche limit effects?" But the problem is that's way too long. Keep thinking about it, I think there's a good clear question in there somewhere!